# How to dispatch Redux action from Firebase auth in React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-redux

I am trying to dispatch a logIn function using the firebase auth listener, as per the docs. But I want to use the listener to trigger a redux action to populate my state.

When I try and run the following code, upon successfully logging in with firebase, it fails with "Cannot read property 'logIn' of undefined.

Please halp

```js
class RootApp extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        // Listen for Auth Changes
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user) {
                this.props.logIn(
                    uid,
                    displayName,
                    photoURL,
                    providerId,
                    email,
                    emailVerified
                );
                // User is signed in.
            } else {
                console.log("Not logged in");
                // No user is signed in.
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.auth.checking == true) {
            return (
                <ActivityIndicator
                    animating={true}
                    style={styles.activityIndicator}
                    size="large"
                />
            );
        } else if (this.props.auth.signedIn == true) {
            return <SignedIn />;
        } else {
            return <SignedOut />;
        }
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        fontSize: 96
    },
    activityIndicator: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        height: 80
    }
});

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        auth: state.auth
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        logIn: (
            uid,
            displayName,
            photoURL,
            providerId,
            email,
            emailVerified
        ) => {
            dispatch(
                logIn(
                    uid,
                    displayName,
                    photoURL,
                    providerId,
                    email,
                    emailVerified
                )
            );
        }
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RootApp);
```

Answer (score -1):

For others that strike this, the answer was to convert the firebase example listener function to a fat arrow function, as the old fashioned function used in their example bound it's own 'this', which arrow functions don't do.

So this:

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

Needs to be changed to:

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {